# filter json file in python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using an api
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/AAPL?apikey=demo

```
"symbol" : "AAPL",
  "historical" : [ {
    "date" : "2015-01-20",
    "open" : 107.84,
    "high" : 108.97,
    "low" : 106.5,
    "close" : 108.72,
    "volume" : 4.98999E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 4.98999E7,
    "change" : -0.88,
    "changePercent" : -0.816,
    "vwap" : 108.06333,
    "label" : "January 20, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : -0.00816
  }, {
    "date" : "2015-01-21",
    "open" : 108.95,
    "high" : 111.06,
    "low" : 108.27,
    "close" : 109.55,
    "volume" : 4.85759E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 4.85759E7,
    "change" : -0.6,
    "changePercent" : -0.551,
    "vwap" : 109.62667,
    "label" : "January 21, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : -0.00551
  },
```

where I want to get the tabulated pandas format with all the columns:

```
date open high low close volume
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), as follows:

Assuming your json file has already been loaded and is named `data`:

```
cols = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
df = pd.json_normalize(data['historical'])[cols]
```

**Input:**

```
data = {"symbol" : "AAPL",
  "historical" : [ {
    "date" : "2015-01-20",
    "open" : 107.84,
    "high" : 108.97,
    "low" : 106.5,
    "close" : 108.72,
    "volume" : 4.98999E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 4.98999E7,
    "change" : -0.88,
    "changePercent" : -0.816,
    "vwap" : 108.06333,
    "label" : "January 20, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : -0.00816
  }, {
    "date" : "2015-01-21",
    "open" : 108.95,
    "high" : 111.06,
    "low" : 108.27,
    "close" : 109.55,
    "volume" : 4.85759E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 4.85759E7,
    "change" : -0.6,
    "changePercent" : -0.551,
    "vwap" : 109.62667,
    "label" : "January 21, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : -0.00551
  }
  ]}
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)


         date    open    high     low   close      volume
0  2015-01-20  107.84  108.97  106.50  108.72  49899900.0
1  2015-01-21  108.95  111.06  108.27  109.55  48575900.0
```